# Tridion Not allowing to Update component if there any metadata keyword which Contains & char

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme

We recently update Tridion 2013 sp1 to Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1

We are not able to update component if there any keyword in component metadata which Contains & char in its Value field Like if there is a keyword which contains Value as 'News & anouncement'

if we create a new component using this kind of keyword in metadata it got saved but if try to update the same component it stuck in save process

Comment: Do you have anything in the Cm event viewer log?  How about if you look at the browser console log (Hit F12 in Chrome and save the component again)?

Answer (score 1):

I think hotfix  CME_2013.1.1.88649 will address this issue. Can you please try that fix on your side and let us know if it solves the problem?

Comment: After applying hotfix CME_2013.1.1.88649 problem get resolved.